# Coq: set default implicit parameters

Tags: implicit, coq

Suppose I have a code with a lot of modules and sections. In some of them there are polymorphic definitions.

```
Module MyModule.

   Section MyDefs.

      (* Implicit. *)
      Context {T: Type}. 

      Inductive myIndType: Type :=
      | C : T -> myIndType.

   End MyDefs.

End MyModule.

Module AnotherModule.

   Section AnotherSection.

      Context {T: Type}.
      Variable P: Type -> Prop.

      (*              ↓↓         ↓↓ - It's pretty annoying. *)
      Lemma lemma: P (@myIndType T).

   End AnotherSection.

End AnotherModule.
```

Usually Coq can infer the type, but often I still get typing error. In such cases, you have to explicitly specify the implicit type with @, which spoils the readability.

> Cannot infer the implicit parameter _ of _ whose type is "Type".

Is there a way to avoid this? Is it possible to specify something like default parameters, which will be substituted every time Coq cannot guess a type?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a typeclass to implement this notion of default value:

```
Class Default (A : Type) (a : A) :=
  withDefault { value : A }.

Arguments withDefault {_} {_}.
Arguments value {_} {_}.

Instance default (A : Type) (a : A) : Default A a :=
  withDefault a.

Definition myNat `{dft : Default nat 3} : nat :=
  value dft.

Eval cbv in myNat.
(* = 3 : nat *)
Eval cbv in (@myNat (withDefault 5)).
(* = 5 : nat *)
```